# Scroll de pantalla según un parámetro de la ruta en Angular2

Tags: angular, angular5

Estoy trabajando con Angular 5.

Tengo una pantalla con notas, que se muestran una detrás de otra, en una distribución vertical, que puede ser extensa. Para acceder a la pantalla tengo una ruta definida en "app.routing.ts" de la siguiente manera:

```
{ path: 'notes', component: Notes },
```

quiero poder ver una nota concreta al acceder a la pantalla y he definido la ruta:

```
{ path: 'notes/:noteId', component: Notes },
```

¿Qué puedo hacer para que al acceder a la ruta con la ID se abra la pantalla de notas a esa nota concreta?

Answer (score 0):

Angular de momento no provee una forma automática para hacer esto, pero puedes implementar lo siguiente:

Asumiendo que tienes la ruta inyectada en tu componente:

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

Puedes buscar el Id y saltar a ese punto así:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
    let noteId = params['noteId'];
    try {
      document.querySelector('#' + noteId).scrollIntoView();
    } catch (e) { }
  });
}
```

Puede leer una [pregunta relacionada en StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101756/angular2-routing-with-hashtag-to-page-anchor)

Comment: No me esta funcionando, si obtengo la ID, pero entra en el catch. He probado a poner un ancla en el HTML: `<p id="10"><a href="#10">HACK</a></p>`, usando un 10 como ID en la ruta.

Comment: ¿Cuál es error capturado?

Comment: El error que sale tal cual esta el código es: "Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#11' is not a valid selector", añadi una letra delante de la ID, tal que: `document.querySelector('#a' + noteId).scrollIntoView();` y `<p id="a10">HACK</p>` de acuerdo a la respuesta de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37270787 (deben usarse selectores CSS válidos), ahora el error es: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null"

Comment: El método `document.querySelector()` me esta devolviendo *null* dentro de `ngAfterViewInit()` ya sea con IDs o con clases. Idem `document.getElementById()`

Comment: Tendría que ver el componente entero, no puedo probar el código ahora mismo creando una prueba